# Semantic-ui-react input Fields are clearing if i switch from one tab to other

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

need to hold input values after changing tab.let me consider each tab pane contains form inputs ,the form fields are clearing if i switch between tabs, how to hold these values.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tab ,Input} from 'semantic-ui-react'

const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}><Input /></Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 2', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}></Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 3', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}></Tab.Pane> },
]

const TabExampleSecondaryPointing = () => (
  <Tab menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true }} panes={panes} />
)

export default TabExampleSecondaryPointing
```

is there any way to hold input values after tab change.

Yess got it working!!, here is the code

```
import React from 'react'
import { List, Label, Tab ,Input} from 'semantic-ui-react'

const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', pane: { key: 'tab1', content: <Input />, size: 'massive' } },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 2', pane: { key: 'tab2', content: 'This tab has a center aligned text', textAlign: 'center' } },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 3', pane: { key: 'tab3', content: <div>This tab contains an <Label>JSX</Label> element</div> } },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 4',
    pane: (
      <Tab.Pane key='tab4'>
        <p>This tab has a complex content</p>

        <List>
          <List.Item>Apples</List.Item>
          <List.Item>Pears</List.Item>
          <List.Item>Oranges</List.Item>
        </List>
      </Tab.Pane>
    ) },
]

const TabExampleContentShorthand = () => (
  <Tab panes={panes} renderActiveOnly={false} />
)

export default TabExampleContentShorthand
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Took me a while to discover this.

Answer (score 1):

`renderActiveOnly={false}` only works when you provide the pane content in a pane object therefore if render is used for the pane content, `renderActiveOnly={false}` will not work.

Examples (from the question):

`renderActiveOnly={false}` will not work:

```
const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}><Input /></Tab.Pane> },
]
```

`renderActiveOnly={false}` will work:

```
const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', pane: { key: 'tab1', content: <Input />, size: 'massive' } },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with API of the `Tab` component, by default it renders only current active tab. So when you switch to another tab, it looses state.

Take a look on the example with [`renderActiveOnly={false}`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab#tab-example-basic-all), it should solve your problem.